# WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, redis

I want to debug my spring-boot application but I couldnt launch the debugger mode on Intellij IDE.

I am getting following errors

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/fedex/ground/transportation/fxglhlschedulesvc/config/RedisConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jedisConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisProperties' defined in file [C:\Users\3895631\Desktop\Repo\fxg-lhl-schedule-svc\build\classes\java\main\com\fedex\ground\transportation\fxglhlschedulesvc\config\RedisProperties.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.redis.port' in value "${spring.redis.port}"

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisProperties' defined in file [C:\Users\3895631\Desktop\Repo\fxg-lhl-schedule-svc\build\classes\java\main\com\fedex\ground\transportation\fxglhlschedulesvc\config\RedisProperties.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.redis.port' in value "${spring.redis.port}"

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.redis.port' in value "${spring.redis.port}"
```

RedisConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.password:}")
    private String redisPassword;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(RedisProperties redisProperties) {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration =
                new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisProperties.getRedisHost(), redisProperties.getRedisPort());
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(redisPassword));
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return template;
    }

}
```

RedisProperties class

```
@Configuration
public class RedisProperties {
    private final int redisPort;
    private final String redisHost;

    public RedisProperties(
            @Value("${spring.redis.port}") int redisPort,
            @Value("${spring.redis.host:localhost}") String redisHost) {
        this.redisPort = redisPort;
        this.redisHost = redisHost;
    }

    public int getRedisPort() {
        return redisPort;
    }

    public String getRedisHost() {
        return redisHost;
    }
}
```

application - properties

```
spring:
  profiles: local
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6340
  application:
    name: fxg-lhl-schedule-svc
server.port: 9092
```

At this point I followed and tried most of the solutions that are out there on similar troubleshooting threads but no luck so far.

I want to know how can I resolve this?

Comment: I see the YAML configuration file, but is the fileName actually application - properties? Also, why're you mixing properties and yml convention in the same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a default value like below -

`@Value("${spring.redis.port:6340}")`

Comment: were you able to run your application?

Comment: Thanks for confirming. But i am still suspicious about the error log you shared. So basically as per this error `IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.redis.port'` spring was not able to find the property. Thats why it is complaining.
Can you check whether spring is able to read other properties from application.properties.

Comment: Tip : check for the location of application.properties file. It should be under `src -> main -> resources` folder.

Comment: Yes. it can read all the properties from properties file but it throws those error while launching debugger.

Comment: Can you upvote the answer if you think the answer was useful?